# How can add space\margin between two elements in iTextSharp\iText?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am pretty new in **iTextSharpt** (the **iText** porting for C#) and I have the following doubt.

In my code I have something like it:

```
iTextSharp.text.Paragraph titolo = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(currentVuln.Title, _fontTitolo0);
titolo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
_document.Add(titolo);

table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.WidthPercentage = 98;

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);

table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");

_document.Add(table);
```

As you can see I simply print a title (usinga **Paragraph** object) and under it a place a table.

The problem is that there is no space (margin) between my title and my table and the graphic result is not good, this is what I obtain in the generated PDF:

[image]

What can I do to add some space\margin between the title paragraph and the table? What is the best way to do it? I am trying to do it but, untill now, I have found no solution

Tnx

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have a couple of different options. You could set the `SpacingAfter` on your paragraph:

```
titolo.SpacingAfter = 20;
```

You could also set the `SpacingBefore` on the table:

```
table.SpacingBefore = 20;
```

Or you could just add some returns to your paragraph:

```
iTextSharp.text.Paragraph titolo = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("Hello World\n\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use set margins to adjust the padding space of your page.

`Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);`
`pdfDoc.SetMargins(20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);`

You can adjust the size value according to your need.

Comment: The OP wanted additional space between title and table, not between page borders and content.